# spring MVC security API issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

2.5 and 5.2.3 spring security apis.
Step 1 : created a class

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
    .permitAll();
}
```

Step 2 : created a custom view

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticateTheUser" method="POST">
    <!-- Check for login error -->

    <p>
        User name: <input type="text" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    </p>    
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form:form>
```

In this case whenever i run the code and login it redirects me on the same loginpage where as it should redirect me to home view

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String getHomeView() {
    return "Home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need more configuration on your HttpSecurity: defaultSuccessUrl

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
        .permitAll();
}
```